# Is there a way to get the actual joystick.Vertical and joystick.Horizontal Value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, joystick

I'm trying to make a moba game by my own.

What I want to do is

1. Pass a parameter called joystick_tag. (like this: Get3DJoystickPosition(joystick_tag))
2. Get current joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical, Camera.main so that I can calculate the value:

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3((joystick.Horizontal + 1) * Screen.width / 2, (joystick.Vertical + 1) * Screen.height / 2, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
```

3. return that value.

It seems quite simple, but in my code the joystick.Horizontal and the joystick.Vertical value keeps 0 even if I move the joystick.

Basically, the method gets a string input, called joystick_tag.
then by the tag, every time the method gets called, it finds a joystick tagged by the tag. Then it calls the Update() method so that I can get the current joystick.Horizontal and joystick.Vertical.

This is the full code. Joystick class is from the Joystick Pack by Fenerax Studios:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Korselo.JoyPos
{
    public class JoyPos : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Joystick joystick;
        public Vector3 world_v;
        public string joystick_tag_public;
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
          
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            world_v = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3((joystick.Horizontal + 1) * Screen.width / 2, (joystick.Vertical + 1) * Screen.height / 2, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));

            Debug.Log(world_v);
        }

        public Vector3 Get3DJoystickPosition(string joystick_tag)
        {
            GameObject joystickGameObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(joystick_tag);
            if (joystickGameObject != null)
            {
                joystick = joystickGameObject.GetComponent<Joystick>();
            }
            Update();
            return world_v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Howdy, just a basic tip.  Your code in "Get3DJoystickPosition" should basically be **inside** Update, not the other way around.  You can't call Update yourself.  Unity calls it for you every frame.  So, if you want to check the joystick every frame, simply check it actually inside Update!  Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh, I should've insert the picture, because Get3DJoystickPosition isn't called every frame.

Comment: Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4HWz.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYtvW.png

Comment: you must not call Update (anywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your code looks like a mess. I highly suggest you take a course or use Unity Learn to begin with before making a MOBA. And you shouldn't call `Update()` yourself. Unity calls it himself. To answer your question, `joystick.Horizontal` and `joystick.Vertical` should return you the actual values.